# What is the difference between $document.ready and $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded')?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I'm using AngularJS and I want to run some actions when the DOM has been fully rendered.
It seems I can either watch the '$viewContentLoaded' event or use the jQuery 'ready' method on the document.

Which of these two methods is the best way to go and why ?

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', [])
.run(function($document, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        console.log('view content loaded');
    });

    $document.ready(function () {
        console.log('document ready');            
    });
});
```

Comment: I added an answer to try to describe the differences, but as I was writing the answer it occurred to me that this *seems like* an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  "run some actions when the DOM has been fully rendered" has a lot of different implications, and the vast majority of them are dealt with by angular automatically....  If my answer doesn't clarify your concerns, you might want to update the question with an example of ***why*** you are worried about the DOM in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$document.ready()` is a call outside Angular which occurs *once* when the DOM is ready for JavaScript to execute.  It is not called by Angular on change in `$location`.  Therefore, the only use for this function in relation to Angular is if you want to manually use `angular.bootstrap()`.  Since Angular must wait for `$document.ready()`, even when using `ng-app`, any code other than manual bootstrap should be handled by controllers.

`$viewContentLoaded` is an Angular event which is a part of the [`ng-route` module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView).  It is emitted by `ngView` whenever the content of the `ng-view` element is reloaded.  The event is angular aware, meaning that it causes a digest cycle, and any code executed as a result of watching this event will affect the content view.  Also, this event will emit every time a new route is loaded, unlike `$document.ready()`, which only emits once.

In general, if your goal is to initialize variables at app start, then initializing them in a controller is the safe choice.  If your goal is to initialize variables every time a new view is rendered, this can usually *also* be done in the controller for each view, but `$viewContentLoaded` is a reasonable fallback.  `$document.ready()` should almost never be used in conjunction with an Angular application, since it is not an Angular aware function.

Answer (score 1):

If you'll look into their definitions, [$rootscope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) is the base scope that you start your app from. [$document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document), on the other hand, represent the entire javascript `window.document` .

Then, it is possible that the part of the DOM that contains your app will be ready, but not the entire document.

I should note that on most web-apps (at least those i saw), the $rootscope was on the body tag, and in that case it's practically the same.